# Get Image Url In Custom Email Template From Theme - Magento2

Tags: magento2, email-templates

The following code exists in Magento 1 to get an image in template syntax, is there a way to do this in Magento 2 and load an image from my theme for the email template? I want to add additional images to the footer.

```
<div sytle="background: {{skin url="images/myimage.png" _area="frontend" _theme="default" _package="mytheme"}}"></div>
```

Comment: Where is your image exist ? i mean in which directory ?

Comment: I have the answer, I can write my own answer and accept that, or if you want to provide an answer as an example I can accept that?

Comment: Yes can post your own answer and accept that , dats ok

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Code for accessing an image in a theme web/images folder in Magento 2 email template:

```
<img
     width="180"
     height="52"
     src="{{view url='images/email/youtube.jpg'}}"
     alt="Website Youtube"
 />
```

Comment: I know more than six people have used this, it took me a lot of curiosity when I started using the email template syntax.

Comment: Where i can find this path: images/email/

Comment: I can't remember, but I would guess pub/?